# MongoDB error: $merge cannot be used in a transaction

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a transaction operation and I want to make a merge request into a table (that doesn't have a schema)

This is my implementation but it's not working in transactions, I get: `$merge cannot be used in a transaction`

```
await User.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: new mongoose.mongo.ObjectID(id),
    },
  },
  {
    $merge: {
      into: 'deleted-users',
    },
  },
]).option({ session });
```

is there an alternative to do this scenario which is to add a record in a Newley created collection inside a transaction ?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that `merge` is
***Excluding the following stages*** As we can read in official [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions-operations/#crud-operations):

> The following read/write operations are allowed in transactions: (among  others) ... `aggregate` command.
> **Excluding the following stages**: (among others) `merge`.

And here You have reference to [merge](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-merge) and more...